# how do I revise my original question

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My question went out when only 10% complete. I don't know why.

The page says I can revise it, but it does not say how.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9074/how-do-i-revise-my-original-question/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see a little "edit" link just below the tags on my questions.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the bottom of a question that you wrote there should be an "edit" link.  It's a light gray color next to where the tags are displayed.

---

Originally posted by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3